# Groupby multiple colums then plot distribution of corresponding value

Tags: r, pandas, dataframe

I'm having issues trying to replicate this R code with python. (installed: dplyr, ggplot, tidyverse, slider).
This plots the distributions of the normalized log volumes (z-score approach) of BTC/USD and ETH/USD by year. I can't replicate it with Python, there are two tickers BTC/USD and ETH/USD, I can group them and plot their densities separately with:

```
fig,ax = df3.groupby('ticker')['normlogvolumesZ'].plot.kde()
```

But not completely replicate the code below.

```
norm_volume %>%
   ggplot(aes(x=normlogvolume, color = year)) +
   geom_density() +
   facet_wrap(~ticker, scales = 'free') +
   ggtitle('Histogram of Normalized yearly Volume')
```

This is the resulting plot: [image: 1]

Our data sets are identical after doing some wrangling:

```
ticker  date    open    high    low close   volume  day year    logvolume   normlogvolumes  normlogvolumesZ
166757  BTC/USD 2019-07-21 13:00:00+00:00   10529.0 10593.5 10492.0 10535.5 1.052900e+00    21  2019    0.719253    0.037261    -3.003460
166758  BTC/USD 2019-07-21 14:00:00+00:00   10534.5 10549.5 10345.0 10408.5 0.000000e+00    21  2019    0.000000    0.000000    -3.183291
166759  BTC/USD 2019-07-21 15:00:00+00:00   10408.5 10483.5 10353.5 10457.0 0.000000e+00    21  2019    0.000000    0.000000    -3.183291
166760  BTC/USD 2019-07-21 16:00:00+00:00   10454.5 10479.5 10370.0 10378.0 0.000000e+00    21  2019    0.000000    0.000000    -3.183291
166761  BTC/USD 2019-07-21 17:00:00+00:00   10374.0 10472.5 10330.0 10429.0 8.451135e+01    21  2019    4.448649    0.230464    -2.071020
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
335578  ETH/USD 2021-11-04 20:00:00+00:00   4492.3  4528.5  4483.5  4514.6  1.928209e+07    4   2021    16.774687   0.869020    1.010789
335579  ETH/USD 2021-11-04 21:00:00+00:00   4514.6  4530.9  4505.9  4525.4  7.954816e+06    4   2021    15.889288   0.823152    0.789418
335580  ETH/USD 2021-11-04 22:00:00+00:00   4525.4  4535.2  4504.4  4518.8  1.153780e+07    4   2021    16.261140   0.842416    0.882390
335581  ETH/USD 2021-11-04 23:00:00+00:00   4518.8  4539.4  4513.6  4535.3  1.296507e+07    4   2021    16.377770   0.848458    0.911550
335582  ETH/USD 2021-11-05 00:00:00+00:00   4535.3  4539.3  4495.8  4507.1  9.938260e+06    5   2021    16.111903   0.834684    0.845077
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split plots by year, you can use this code:

```r
df %>% ggplot(aes(x = normlogvolumesZ, color = ticker)) + geom_density() + facet_wrap(~year)
```

[image]

If you want to split plots by ticker, you should change format of column `year` from `numeric` to `factor` or `character`. It's because we put this column as `color` argument. Code:

```r
df$year = as.factor(df$year)
df %>% ggplot(aes(x = normlogvolumesZ, color = year)) + geom_density() + facet_wrap(~ticker)
```

[image]

P.S. My test data. Please add code like this in your next questions^

```r
df = data.frame(
    ticker = c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 10)),
    normlogvolumesZ = c(rnorm(10, 0, 3), rnorm(10, 0, 1)),
    year = c(rep(2019, 3), rep(2020, 3), rep(2021, 4), rep(2019, 3), rep(2020, 3), rep(2021, 4))
)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, that's how you'd density plot volumes by ticker but i'm looking to do that AND have individual plots by year. So grouping by ticker AND year and then plotting volumes by ticker + year. Unless i'm missing something.

Comment: You python example `fig,ax = df3.groupby('ticker')['normlogvolumesZ'].plot.kde()` do it?

Comment: That yields two distributions by Ticker but what i'm shooting for was two distributions by ticker and year. I did manage some success using seaborn and the groupby object.

`grouped = df3.groupby('ticker')
groupbit = grouped.get_group('BTC/USD')#.set_index('year')
groupeth = grouped.get_group('ETH/USD')
#groupbit.head()
f1 = sns.histplot(data=groupbit, x='normlogvolumesZ', hue='year',kde=True)`

Comment: I run your python code and it returns plots which is not equal to your, and I forget about your image. Now I understand what you want)

Comment: All good! Yeah it's somewhat complicated, I think I might need to merge and/or use  the .pivot_table() function. I'm trying to do this in python btw, not in R.